# How do I make array move together?

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to follow a low poly flower tutorial but when it says to add an array modifier for the petals and then move them up they turn into a spiral. How do I get them to move together?[image]

Comment: Did u move the empty?

Comment: Can you post a link to the tutorial (i it's online) we might be able to show you where the issue is.

Comment: They start moving it at 3:04 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJa-6eAujoM

Answer (score 1):

It's because your empty is not at the same location as your object origin, so the distance between the origin and the empty shifts the iterations. What you can do is:

- Select the object
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*
- Select your empty
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*

It should work.